# update sql query in new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in which i have 'goswara no. 21/1980' i need only 21 and  year from date column like this col gr=21/year(date) through sql2005 query

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Might be helpful to be more specific in your question. Do read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can you add the queries you tried? And some more about your table structure?

Comment: i have'nt try anyone kindly suggest me some

Comment: remarks(varchar(100) in which text and date  and new col need to add name gr no extracted from remarks

Comment: If sql server 2005 has the patindex function use it.  Or, if the alpha part is always 'goswara no. ', count the characters and use string functions.  Otherwise, you might be in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf991/6

something like this?
select
right(columnname,4) as year ,
SUBSTRING ( columnname ,len(columnname) - 6 ,2 ) as result
from test